# how to access a shadowed gradle property

Tags: gradle, jar, properties, shadowing

How can I access a gradle property variable that is shadowed by some other property in the current context?

Example:

gradle.properties

```
version = 1.0
someOtherVar = test
```

build.gradle

```
apply plugin 'java'
jar {
    archiveVersion = "${version}-${someOtherVar}"
}
```

In that context `${version}` refers to the [jar.version](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar:version) instead of the property having the same name (property version is shadowed by jar version). How can I get the value of the version property in the `jar` context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The project's `version` fields can be accessed via the FQN `project.version` (for the current project) or `rootProject.version` (for the root project).

Answer (score 0):

While in this specific case, you could use the [Project.version](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Project.html#org.gradle.api.Project:version) property, in a more general case, use the [Project.property(propertyName)](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Project.html#org.gradle.api.Project:property(java.lang.String)) method:

```gradle
apply plugin 'java'
jar {
    archiveVersion = "${property('version')}-${someOtherVar}"
}
```